# Copy/Paste loop code

Tags: 16.04, command-line, bash, directory, paste

I am new in Linux so here is my very basic question. I have a directory with 41 folders. I need to create a loop so that the process goes into each folder, copy all the files and then paste everything in a specific folder.

Any idea how to approach this? It would be a lot of clicking without a code solution

In the image you can see all the folders I need to access and the output folder where I want to paste everything (zPASTE_EVERYTHING_HERE)

[image: Directory]

My path is: `/shared/home/data/output`

Would like to paste everything in: `/shared/home/data/output/zPASTE_EVERYTHING_HERE`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that:

- The folders to be copied and their files are under `/home/gcgm/myfolders`
- The output folder is `/tmp/output-folder`

If you need to copy all files to another folder, you can do the following:

```
mkdir /tmp/output-folder
cd /home/gcgm/myfolders
cp */* /tmp/output-folder
```

---

The meaning of `*/* in the this command`cp */* target` is:

- Take all files (*the 2nd **) in all directories (*the first **) under the current directory.

Comment: Would that work as a loop through each folder? I have written down my path so that it is easier for a complety new linux user like me

Comment: if will copy all files in all folders under the current-folder, into the output-folder, this solution doesn't use loop.

Comment: its working perfectly. Could you just explain what the last line of your code is doing? What is `cp */*`?

Comment: just wondering, would it be possible to cut - paste instead of copy - paste?

Comment: @GCGM, replace `cp` with `mv` for cut-paste.

Answer (score 6):

Based on your example, your destination directory does not contain any digit whereas all your source directories do. So, you can simply use (GNU) `cp` like below from the parent directory, in `bash`:

```
shopt -s dotglob  #Enables matching hidden files with glob patterns
shopt -s globstar #Enables recursive traverse of directories
cp -t zPASTE_EVERYTHING_HERE *[[:digit:]]*/**/*
```

- `cp` does the copying
- `-t zPASTE_EVERYTHING_HERE` sets the destination directory
- `*[[:digit:]]*/**/*` matches directories containing at least a digit, traverses into them (at any depth too) and gets everything.

---

Doing everything in a subshell to keep the parent shell intact; from parent directory:

```
( shopt -s dotglob && shopt -s globstar && \
    cp -t zPASTE_EVERYTHING_HERE *[[:digit:]]*/**/* )
```

---

Now, for any random destination directory name, set the directory as `GLOBIGNORE` variable:

```
GLOBIGNORE=whatever_destination
```

Now, you can simply do:

```
cp -t whatever_destination */**/*
```

or you can leverage `extglob`:

```
shopt -s extglob #Should be already set on any interactive shell session
cp -t whatever_destination !(whatever_destination)/**/*
```

---

**Additional note:**

There is a chance of `ARG_MAX` being triggered if you have many files/directories inside the source directories, in that case you have two options:

- Use a `for` construct to iterate over the files one by one, this would be very slow as you can imagine:

  ```
  for f in !(whatever_destination)/**/*; do cp -- "$f" whatever_destination/; done
  ```
- Use `find`:

  ```
  find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -not -name whatever_destination \
      -name '*' -exec sh -c 'cp -rt whatever_destination "$1"/*' _ {} \;
  ```

Comment: Thanks for you reply. It's working as well. Just wondering if having a digit in my destination folder would affect your solution? So far it is a random name

Comment: @GCGM Yes, check my edits.